# Cisco PIX land attack

Tags: cisco, cisco-pix

I am continouly getting errors log `Deny IP due to Land Attack from IP to IP`.

Both source and destination IP address are same.

Can any one please guide me what could be the issue and how I can fix this?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions.  You might want to ask this over on ServerFault or SuperUser...

Comment: What PIX OS are you using ? Answers are right but this may also be an false alert if your are running PIX one of the first v7 version

Answer (score 5):

The Land Attack spoofs the source and destination IP to be the same basically causing the machine to continuously reply to itself causing a DOS.  It's a pretty old attack and most OS's are now patched to not be vulnerable to this.

In this case I think your PIX is doing what it's supposed to and dropping the traffic.  I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure there is something to "fix" in this case.  There are a number of baseline security protections that are enabled in PIXOS, [Land Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_attack) protection being one of them.

One possibility you could do is check the MAC table in the PIX for the offending and attempt to track it down for remediation.  However, I would not necessarily trust the results to be completely accurate.